# how to configure settings in developer facebook?

Tags: javascript, plone

I used plone 4.3 my site name is *localhost:8080/alpster*. I created sample page with facebook login.now when i click login button I got error like

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

my configure settings :

```
 developer.facebook.com--->>>settings----> basic

           namespace="alpster-login"
           App Domains=alpster
           Contact Email=my valid email
           Site URL=localhost.com:8080
```

any one can solve my problem

Comment: Is your `localhost.com:8080` a copy/paste typo for `localhost:8080`?

Comment: my site is localhost:8080. i referred the link so only i use this way

Answer (score 1):

Might not be able to use localhost, but I can't remember specifically.

If you are using localhost, you can't use .com in the appdomain. If doesnt let you do otherwise, then that means you must use an actual domain, not localhost. Use something like http://localtunnel.me/ to get around this.

Otherwise, just need to make sure the canvas & web urls match each other.